# Where can i find detailed documentation about how to implement Swiper slider in React?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Does anyone know how to implement the Swiper slider properly in React? Basically, I want to know how to implement autoplay, loop, and navigation buttons properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please visit swiper docs: [https://swiperjs.com/demos#]